# OpenGL apps (Games) disappear after leaving fullscreen

Tags: games, steam

I've been trying to play some linux supported games on ubuntu 12.04 using steam (mostly Dota 2) and I've been having the same problem every time with every game.
As soon as I alt-tab out of fullscreen mode the game just vanishes.
Its still running in the background, it still shows up on the system monitor but I have no way of accessing the game again.
It doesn't show on the task bar, doesn't show on Alt-Tabs... just weird.

Granted, I am a complete linux noob (as in I google absolutely everything I do) so I might be missing something incredibly obvious here... o.O

Comment: I frequently accidentally open the dash while toggling autocast, and I found that sometimes, when you don't see Dota 2, clicking the Steam icon in the sidebar a few times will usually make it reappear.

Comment: As John said, with Steam the game minimizes to the Steam Icon, if you look closely you will see 2 arrows showing that the Steam client ans Dota are both open, clicking on the icon will spread the apps back out and then you can click on Dota's screen to get it back to the front.  other than steam games, I don't know of any others that do this, native games (tuxcart for ex) will have it's own icon that you can click on the get it back

Answer (score -1):

Go to the steam and reclick the steam icon again this should make you select things that runs on steam well atleast it is for me